# java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, netbeans

i need a help when i execute the following MYSQL command in Navicat i get

```
mysql> SELECT Password FROM workers;

    +----------+
    | Password |
    +----------+
    | A        |
    | B        |
    | B        |
    | B        |
    | B        |
```

when i fire it in java i get

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2.
```

Code :-

```
try {
       ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees", "root", "123456");
       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Password FROM workers");
       int c =1;
       while(rs.next())  
       {
           A.add(rs.getString(c));
           c++;
       }
       con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only getting 1 column, you are out of range. You change your code as follows, and remove your counter.

```
try {
         ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees", "root", "123456");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Password FROM workers");

        while(rs.next())  
        {
          A.add(rs.getString("Password"));

        }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir much appreciated !

Comment: You are welcome. Consider accepting my answer with the check.

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 entries in your database table and execute the following code:

```
int c = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
    A.add(rs.getString(c)); // get value at column
    c++;
}
```

- 1st iteration: `rs.getString(1)`, get value at column 1
- 2nd iteration: `rs.getString(2)`, get value at column 2
- and so on

Now, your table only has one column, therefore you should access your value with either

- `rs.getString(int column)`, here **always** 1
- `rs.getString(String columnLabel)`, here Password